# Access Query where field populates if only matching another field

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to figure out this query. I'm creating a make a table query and combining data from two tables, however I think it may be better to do a Crosstab query. Tables are Attendance and Intake. I want the field "username" and "attendance status" from Attendance table and "assignedto" and "actiondate" from the Intake table. I'm trying to be able to track which workers are available from the attendance tab and the number of cases assigned to them to populate from the "assignedto" only if the "actiondate" field is today's date and "assignedto" has names and should only populate if the name matches the "username" from the Attendance table as well. I hope that makes sense.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Save this as 001:

```
SELECT
att.username, 
att.[attendance status], 
intake.assignedto, 
intake.actiondate
FROM Attendance att
INNER JOIN intake on att.username = intake.assignedto
WHERE intake.actiondate = NOW();
```

Now create a make table query that uses 001 as it's datasource.

Explanation of 001: the `INNER JOIN` helps meet the criteria you mention of "[...] and "assignedto" has names and should only populate if the name matches the "username" from the Attendance table as well".  This will only return records from each table where this value matches.
There `WHERE intake.actiondate = NOW()` helps further restrict the results to only those records where the actiondate is today.

Comment: Thank you for the coding but nothing populated and there should have been some records that were pulled.

Comment: @Lilly - try removing the WHERE statement.  If the query still returns no records, try posting some example data.  Also, if you are pasting my query text into Access, please make sure the field and table names I used actually match what is in your database.

Comment: I removed that entire statement and no data populates still. I changed the table and field names to the proper names prior to running the query.

Comment: Are the values in att.username the same as the values in intake.assignedTo?

Comment: Yes they are just the first names of the employees so there should be matching data.

Comment: Can you post an example of names from `att.username` and `intake.assignedto`

Comment: an example would be like Lillian or Amy

Comment: I was hoping you could modify your original question with examples from the data.  If you removed the `WHERE` statement and you are still not getting results then that indicates that the values in username and assignedto are not equivalent at all.